# Woocommerce product categories order

Tags: categories, plugins

Is it possible to sort product categories?

I have a category with a lot of subcategories. On the category page all the subcategories is listed. Right now I can only change the order by drag and drop in the admin panel. But that is very time consuming with a lot of categories. Any way to change the order without using drag and drop?

Comment: Did I ask the question in a wrong way? I got a minus, but I'm not sure why. Something I should change or have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woocommerce stores 'order' metakeys in the table `wp_woocommerce_termmeta`. The mechanism it uses is the same as `menu_order` for posts.

Something like this should work:

```
$terms = get_terms('product_cat');

//sort $terms somehow

$i = -1;

foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $i++;
  update_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->id, 'order', $i);
}
```

The same procedure can be used to sort other Woocommerce taxonomies such as `product_tag` and **Product Attributes**. For a Product Attribute named Size, the taxonomy would be `pa_size`, and you should replace 'order' by `order_pa_size`

Comment: I would +2 that answer if I could

Answer (score 1):

You can sort product categories by drag-and-drop. Notice that your mouse cursor turns into a hand when over a category row? Grab it and drag to its new position in the list. Job is done.

Comment: Yeah, I have just done it with drag and drop. It does however take a long time with over 100 categories. Thanks for the answer.