# What is table `wp_woocommerce_termmeta` for?

Tags: database, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using [Woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) plugin for my Wordpress website.

After added, I notice that there is a table called **wp_woocommerce_termmeta**. What is this table storing?

p.s.

Is there any relationship between **wp_woocommerce_termmeta**.`woocommerce_term_id` column and **wp_terms**.`term.id`

A snapshot on this table data in the context after I imported [dummy Woocommerce product data](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/importing-woocommerce-dummy-data/) is as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce stores 'order' metakeys in the table wp_woocommerce_termmeta. The mechanism it uses is the same as menu_order for posts.

Check this [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80068/woocommerce-product-categories-order) for reference.

Thanks

Comment: How about other `meta_key` as `product_count_product_cat`?

Comment: wp_woocommerce_termmeta is not updated right when you add, change or remove a product.
For example if you add a product in a category woocommerce should count the amount of products in a certain category and update metakey -> product_count_product_cat. But the script doesn't. 

This function should be activated as soon as you add, edit or delete a product and also when a product is bought.

Basically it stores a relation between product and category